# SWIFT: Parse data is deleted when UIButton Action is performed

Tags: ios, swift

Here are the steps that I'm taking -

Step 1: I enter values in the following fields, and they get saved in the Parse table. Works perfect.

[image]

Step 2: I access this screen again, and click 'Submit' again without editing the fields, and the Parse table row is deleted.

I am trying to figure out why this is happening. The desired functionality is that when the user loads this screen for the first time, the fields are blank. Once this screen is loaded thereafter, the existing values are displaying the fields, and if the user edits the fields and clicks 'Submit', the values will chance.

This is my code for this particular view controller -

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class RSVPViewController: UIViewController {

/*----------- ~ OUTLETS AND ACTIONS ~ -----------*/

//View Controller Title Bar Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTitle: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var menuTitle: UIBarButtonItem!

//View Controller Body Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label4: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var label1Field: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label2Field: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label3Field: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label4Field: UITextField!

//View Controller Body Actions
@IBAction func submitButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let query = PFQuery(className:"RSVPData")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let objects = objects! as? [PFObject] {

                for object in objects {

                    object.deleteInBackground()

                }
            }

        } else {

            print(error)
        }
    }

    let RSVPData = PFObject(className: "RSVPData")

    RSVPData["label1"] = label1Field.text
    RSVPData["label2"] = label2Field.text
    RSVPData["label3"] = label3Field.text
    RSVPData["label4"] = label4Field.text
    RSVPData["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username

    RSVPData.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if (success) {

            if let error = error {

                if let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                    self.displayAlert("Failed", message: errorString)

                }


            } else {

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("RSVPToMain", sender: self)

            }


        } else {

            // There was a problem, check error.description

        }
    }


}

/*----------- ~ MAIN THREAD ~ -----------*/

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Run title bar function
    TitleBar()

    label1.text = "Label 1"
    label2.text = "Label 2"
    label3.text = "Label 3"
    label4.text = "Label 4"

    let query = PFQuery(className:"RSVPData")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let objects = objects! as? [PFObject] {

                for object in objects {

                    self.label1Field.text = object["label1"] as? String
                    self.label2Field.text = object["label2"] as? String
                    self.label3Field.text = object["label3"] as? String
                    self.label4Field.text = object["label4"] as? String

                }
            }

        } else {

            print(error)
        }
    }

}

/*----------- ~ FUNCTIONS ~ -----------*/

//Function containing all title bar instructions
func TitleBar() {

    /*----------- ~ NAVIGATION BAR (USER INTERFACE) ~ -----------*/

    //Set the navigation bar tet color and size
    let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    nav?.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)]

    /*----------- ~ OUTLET - 'usernameTitle' ~ -----------*/

    //Set the 'usernameTitle' font and size
    usernameTitle.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 11)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    //Set the 'usernameTitle' outlet to the current user
    usernameTitle.title = PFUser.currentUser()?.username

}

//Function to display an alert
func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
@IBAction func submitButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let query = PFQuery(className:"RSVPData")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if object!.count > 0 {

                if let object = object! as? [PFObject] {

                    for object in object {

                        object["label1"] = self.label1Field.text
                        object["label2"] = self.label2Field.text
                        object["label3"] = self.label3Field.text
                        object["label4"] = self.label4Field.text

                        object.saveInBackground()

                    }

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("RSVPToMain", sender: self)

                }
            } else if object?.count == 0 {

                let RSVPData = PFObject(className: "RSVPData")

                RSVPData["label1"] = self.label1Field.text
                RSVPData["label2"] = self.label2Field.text
                RSVPData["label3"] = self.label3Field.text
                RSVPData["label4"] = self.label4Field.text
                RSVPData["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username

                RSVPData.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if (success) {

                        if let error = error {

                            if let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                                self.displayAlert("Failed", message: errorString)

                            }


                        } else {

                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("RSVPToMain", sender: self)

                        }

                    } else {

                        // There was a problem, check error.description

                    }
                }



            }

        } else {

            print(error)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I am not very proficient in swift but aren't you deleting all the object you find the any with  object.deleteInBackground()  What are you actually trying to do with that statement?

Comment: Instead of these"/*----------- ~ OUTLETS AND ACTIONS ~ -----------*/" comments you really should use //MARK: Outlets and Actions.
That helps the class navigation a lot more than some over verbose comment

Comment: @Yan, when the Submit button is clicked, i would like the old values in the table row to be replaced with the new ones. The way i am doing this is by deleting the old row and adding a new row.  Can you suggest a better way to accomplish this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not need to delete the row if it exists. Instead of deleting the row, you can just update with the new values that you get from the user.  Here is a sample from parse.com website on how to update an existing object.  Let me know if you still have a question and i will try it in Xcode and update it with your code.  https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("xWMyZEGZ") {
  (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error != nil {
    print(error)
  } else if let gameScore = gameScore {
    gameScore["cheatMode"] = true
    gameScore["score"] = 1338
    gameScore.saveInBackground()
  }
}
```

You can use your code and see comments bellow.

```
query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
     query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects! as? [PFObject] {
                //see comments bellow
                //for object in objects {
                    //object.deleteInBackground()

               // }
            }

        } else {

                print(error)
        }
    }
```

When you get the array of objects, you would check if there is only one object  in the array to make sure there is only one row for that user and then do `object["sangeet"] = label1Field.text`
    update all the fields and do `object.saveInBackground();`

==========

## Update

You can create a new row when objects return nil. I am thinking you should be able excuse save operation inside of the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` block I am not very familiar with swift so i copy pasted your code and it should work.  Let me know if you still having issues.

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"RSVPData")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                if let objects = objects! as? [PFObject] {

                    for object in objects {

                        object.deleteInBackground()

                    }
                }else{
                    //assuming that object is nil and there is no record for that user
                    //you would then add the user and information into the database

                    let RSVPData = PFObject(className: "RSVPData")

                    RSVPData["sangeet"] = label1Field.text
                    RSVPData["tibetan"] = label2Field.text
                    RSVPData["hindu"] = label3Field.text
                    RSVPData["reception"] = label4Field.text
                    RSVPData["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username

                    RSVPData.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                        if (success) {

                            if let error = error {

                                if let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                                    self.displayAlert("Failed", message: errorString)

                                }


                            } else {

                                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("RSVPToMain", sender: self)

                            }


                        } else {

                            // There was a problem, check error.description

                        }
                    }

                }

            } else {

                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: this is very helpful, thank you.  I do have one question... If I'm trying to find the row of the current user, what do i replace "xWMyZEGZ" with?

Comment: Thanks @Yan.  Your solution does work for users who have already entered values. However, the issue that I'm still having is that new users aren't able to add values to the table.  Can you please recommend a potential solution? Thanks.

Comment: @SB2015  I am glad i was able to help.   I updated the answer.  Let know if it worked out.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you do delete the row if the username is the same value as your PFUser's username. I have not used Parse before but `object.deleteInBackground()` looks like a delete to me.

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"RSVPData")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects! as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    object.deleteInBackground()
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

So I guess you only delete the entry if you use the same user twice.

Comment: each user can only have one row in the parse table.  When a user inputs the values in these fields for the first time, the row is added.  When the user comes back to this view controller, i would like them to see the existing values in each field, and if they change those values and click Submit, the existing table row is updated. At this point, i am checking to see if the username thats logged in actually has an existing row in the table, and if they do, once Submit is clicked again, it deletes the old row and adds a new one with the new value(s). Can you suggest a better solution?